# Nested containers with subclasses

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I have nested containers A and B. The attributes are there to show that classes have some other members. One of my functions `f` takes another container of such containers (let's say vector again).

```
ContainerA{
    int a;    
    std::vector<ContainerB> contc;    
}

ContainerB{
    int b;    
    std::vector<Element> contd;    
}

class Element{
}

void f (std::vector<ContainerA>& a){}
```

Now, another function needs a vector of`ContainerA` augmented with extra methods and augments elements of type `Element` itself. I want to avoid copying as much as possible and really don't want to template function `f` with Element type. With the rest I am flexible and can take other design decisions.

**Solution:**

Template containers A and B, subclass A and Element, use pointer to Element, to be able to store `LargerElement` in it:

```
class LargerElement: public Element{
   int e;
}
template <class T>
ContainerA{
    int a;    
    std::vector<ContainerB<T>> contc;    
}

template <class T>
ContainerB{
    int b;    
    std::vector<T*> contd;    
}
class LargerContainerA : public ContainerA<Element>{
    int d;
    public LargerContainerA (){
    // need to rewrite constructor to store
    // LargerElement* in Element* for all elements.
    }

}
void f (std::vector<ContainerA<Element>>& a){}
void g (std::vector<LargerContainerA>& la){}
```

The usage is like this:

```
int main(){
   std::vector<ContainerA<Element>*> vec(100);
   for (auto& v: vec){
       v = new LargerContainerA(...); 
   }
   f(vec);

   std::vector<LargerContainerA*> vec2(vec.size());
   for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
       vec2[i] = dynamic_cast<LargerContainerA*>(vec[i]);
   }
   g(lacont); 

   // free memory   
  ...
```

}

But remaining problems are:

1. All of this is ugly.
2. Function `g` then forced to work in terms of Element in subfunctions/classes it calls and dynamic cast to Larger Element every now and then.

Comment: Can you provide more specific information about what you need to do? We need at least an overview about the task that you need to perform. It seems to me that your second loop in 'main' is not necessary, but I need to understand your task first in order to make sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern